# How do I sort alphanumerical keys in Perl?

Tags: linux, perl

I have a hash with keys that look like AA00, AA01, AB00, AB23, ZA03, ZB45, AA02, DA05, AA45, DE67, DE84, ZZ99 and I need to sort them first by letter set then by number from minor to major.

Edit: the case is more complex indeed. Letters must be read from left to right and the number of digits and letter might change. That is, A00 must be before AA00 and AB00. B00 must be after AZ99 but before BA00.

Also, If I find AA, AAA, AAB and AAAA, then AAA, AAB shall be considered a subset that goes before AA, and AAAA shall be before the triple letter subset. But ABAA, for example, must be after AA.

Numbers are in linear order, that is 0 is before 1, and 1 is before 99, but there is no limit for the number of digits. 1 might be represented by 1 or by 01 (See ZB). Ignore the spaces, they are there to maintain the columns.

That is,

```
A   00,
AAAA00,
AAA 00,
AAB 00,
AA  00,
AA  01,
AA  02,
AA  45,
ABAA00,
AB  00, (first letter change)
AB  23,
AZ  99,
B   00,
BA  00,
DA  05, (second letter change, first letter restarts as A)
DE  67,
DE  84,
ZA  03,
ZB  45,
ZB 145,
ZB1145,
ZZ  99,
```

I tried the classical

```
for $key ( sort {$a<=>$b} keys %hash) {
       print "($key)->($hash{$key})\n";
}
```

But no sorting is produced at all. Indeed, keys are passed totally disorganzied.

There is the logic that was used to produced the data set. They used:

```
 While (Certain thing is True) {
   Select a $letter; 
   $identifier .= $letter 
 }
```

It is supposed that the first letter is a represents a Set A, the second letter represents a subset in A. That is, if I hava AA, AB and AC, then A, B and C are subsets in A. If I had ABC, C is a subset in the subset B of the set A. If I had, then, ABCA, the last A is a subset in C.

Comment: Your latest edit is still a little unclear. It would be simpler to just show a set of input strings (including *all* of the edge cases you mention, i.e. `A00`, `AA00`, `AB00`, `B00`, `AZ99`, `BA00`, `AA`, `AAA`, `AAB`, `AAAA`, and `ABAA`) and the sorted output that should be produced.

Comment: Why do you want `A00`, `AAAA00`, `AAA00` in that order? It seems completely arbitrary.

Comment: I think it's got something to do with having more than one pattern of the same length with the same starting letter(s?). But I'm tired of guessing.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot It is a set of data I got. I have no clear idea why the previous user made it that way. In my opinion, there were plenty of options to produce a clearer identifier. Either way, I have to process his/her data and this is the supposedly logic order he/she was attempting. They made a loop that added letter to the identifier. something like

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot While (Certain thing is True) {Select a $letter; $identifier .= $letter } It is supposed that the first letter is a Big Set A, the second letter represents a subset in A. That is AA, AB, AC, then A, B and C are subsets. If I have ABC, C is a subset in the subset B of the set A.

Comment: You say "data set" when you mean "order". If you don't understand the order, how do you expect to explain it to us??? The first thing you need to do is define what your code is suppose to do. Until you do that, noone can help you.

Comment: @je_b Okay, now we're getting somewhere. It sounds like you want to sort top-level (i.e. one-letter) identifiers before their associated subsets, e.g. `A`, `AA`, `AB`, `AC`, `B`, `BA`, `BB`, `BC`, right? But for anything longer than one letter, you switch the order, with the most nested (i.e. longest) identifiers first, e.g. `AAAA`, `AAA`, `AA`. Is that accurate?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Yes

Comment: No, that gives a different order than the one given. This is the fourth incorrect order you've given us.

Answer (score 4):

```
my @sorted =
   map $_->[0],
   sort {
      $a->[1] cmp $b->[1]
         ||
      $a->[2] <=> $b->[2]
   }
   map {
      my ($l, $n) = /^([A-Z]+)([0-9]{1,9})\z/
         or die("Unexpected data");

      $l .= "\xFF" if length($l) > 1;

      [ $_, $l, $n ]
   }
   @unsorted;
```

---

Optimized:

```
my @sorted =
   map { unpack('J/a*', scalar(reverse($_))) }
   sort
   map {
      my ($l, $n) = /^([A-Z]+)([0-9]{1,9})\z/
         or die("Unexpected data");

      pack('a* a* J>', $l, length($l) == 1 ? "\x00" : "\xFF", $n) . reverse(pack('J/a*', $_))
   }
   @unsorted;
```

---

Note: It may be possible to handle larger numbers without changing anything but the check, depending on your build of Perl.

Comment: I made it with 2 letters and 2 numbers in this example but that might not be always the case. If I find AA, AAA, AAB and AAAA, then AAA, AAB shall be considered a subset that goes before AA, and AAAA shall be before the triple letter subset. But ABAA, for example, must be after AA.

Comment: @je_b Edit your question to include a *representative* example of your data, including edge cases.

Comment: @ikegami If I'm reading the OP's comment right, they want `AA AAA AAB AAAA ABAA` to be sorted `AAAA AAA AAB AA ABAA`, so I don't think it's based on the length of the letters, but I can't make heads or tails of the logic behind it.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot It is a set of data I got. I have no clear idea why the previous user made it that way. In my opinion, there were plenty of options to produce a clearer identifier. Either way, I have to process his/her data and this is the supposedly logic order he/she was attempting.

Comment: GIven the use of matches, captures, and function calls I'd implement this as a Schwartzian Transform (map/sort/map) to improve performance.

Comment: Ooh, a GRT! You did me one better! :)

Answer (score -2):

As some of the posters wrote, the question is not completely clear. Nevertheless, my attempt at a solution is below. I have not tested this code, so you may need to tweak it a bit to get it to work.

```
my @sorted_keys = sort by_letters_then_numbers keys %hash;

sub by_letters_then_numbers
{
    if ($a !~ /^([a-zA-Z]+)\s*(\d+)$/) {return 0};
    my $a_letters = $1;
    my $a_number = $2;
    if ($b !~ /^([a-zA-Z]+)\s*(\d+)$/) {return 0};
    my $b_letters = $1;
    my $b_number = $2;
    return(($a_letters cmp $b_letters) || ($a_number <=> $b_number));
}
```